# error when using WebGLRenderer() with jsdom

Tags: node.js, three.js, jsdom

I'm trying to render a cube on server side, and was able to do so using the CanvasRenderer, but i want to be able to render it with WebGLRenderer, which should produce better results. i've narrowed it down to this code snippet:

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom')
, document = jsdom.jsdom('<!doctype html><html><head></head><body></body></html>')
, window = document.createWindow()
, THREE = require('three');

document.onload = docOnLoad();

function docOnLoad()
{
    console.log("docOnLoad called.");
    global.document = document;
    global.window = window;
    //renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer(); //works
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(400, 400);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);     
}
```

When using the WebGLRenderer, i got:

```
_glExtensionTextureFloat = _gl.getExtension( 'OES_texture_float');
                               ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'getExtension' of undefined
    at initGL (C:\programming\nodejs\node_modules\three\three.js:25870:34)
```

when trying to debug three.js code, console.log(_gl) indeed shows that _gl is undefined, and the source of it is line #25856, where:

```
_gl = _canvas.getContext( 'webgl', attributes ) || _canvas.getContext( 'experimental-webgl', attributes );
```

now, console.log() of _canvas shows: `[Canvas 0x0]`
Has anyone encountered something similar?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? Are there any insights? Trying to use headless-gl but failing at the same spot as you.

Comment: Was not able to resolve it, and if I remember correctly, we eventually dropped headless-gl and went for something else completely in the client side

Answer (score 1):

Usually happens when you already obtained a 2D context from _canvas. Both 2D context and gl cannot be obtained from the same canvas. If this is not the case, can you confirm if you are able to successfully run any other WebGL example independently (from node.js) ?

Comment: I don't have 2D context obtained- since i don't pass any canvas element, three.js creates one on its own and the first getContext() call is on line #25856. Will find some WebGL sample and try to run it outside node.js

Comment: Been searching for a while, no luck finding something specific. Also, when trying to getContext('webgl') with the canvas module (npm install canvas) i got "undefined". Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: i have tried with the canvas module, it returns "undefined". also, when three.js module creates the webgl context, it tries to do so with getContext('webgl') or getContext('experimental-webgl'), neither works in my case.

Comment: To isolate a bit, can you try the example usage given in node-webgl module (https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-webgl) ?

Comment: Will try that, also i found "headless-gl" which should be even simpler- but both have some dependencies so it'll take some time. Thank you for now!